# Is there any option to debug issue in config.xml?

Tags: configuration, xml

Is there anyone provide solution to debug the issue of **config.xml** in Magento ?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I have setup a new module and it is not listing in Configuration -> Advanced Section of Magento Admin Panel.

Comment: you have to add `app/etc/modules/Spacename_Modulename.xml` file  so we can look what is possible error and also add `config.xml` in question too

Comment: I will take care of that issue as I did it previously. Actually most of the times it is like wrong closing tag or missing tag or spelling mistake so I will resolve that. I just wanted to know if there is any tool or solution which can debug the config.xml and output the error.

Comment: i added some online tools for that but specific to magento

Answer (score 2):

alan storm has created one of the great extension which I am also using

just create a module as suggested in the blog and check

http://alanstorm.com/magento_config/

after creating above extension

try  `http://magento.example.com/?showConfig=true` and check you will see all config code which is used in current page

this way you can debug the config file

Answer (score 1):

There are some online tool available for validate the xml

https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator